# How to use StoreApi in zustand

Tags: reactjs, typescript, zustand

From the docs of [zustand](https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand#middleware) I found that together with `set` and `get` parameters they provide an additional parameter at StateCreator, called `api`.

Example bellow

```
import create, { StateCreator } from 'zustand'
import type { Store } from './store.types'

const globalStateCreator: StateCreator<Store> = (set, get, api) => ({
    ...mySlice(set, get, api),
})
```

What does it stands for? What are the best practices for using it?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using React, you're probably using hooks to do something like this:

```js
const color: PaletteColor = usePaintbrush((s) => s.color);
```

The hooks make zustand seem more self-contained than it really is. You have *a lot* of control over the state.

Hooks are limited to components, but you can use the api methods bound to the store from anywhere, imperatively.

```js
// .ts
const color: PaletteColor = usePaintbrush.getState().color[shade];
```

```js
// .tsx
const color = useRef<PaletteColor>(usePaintbrush.getState().color[shade]);
useEffect(() => usePaintbrush.subscribe((s) => (color.current = s.color[shade])), [shade])
```

Store actions are not required to be in the store either!

```js
// at module level
const setColor = (color: PaletteColor) => usePaintbrush.setState({ color })
```

You're unlikely to touch the api parameter unless you're creating a middleware.

---

Docs cover specific example usage with the persist middleware

> The persist api enables you to do numbers of interactions with the persist middleware from inside or outside a React component.

---

references (updated [#1033](https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand/discussions/1033)):

- [store without actions](https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand/blob/main/docs/guides/practice-with-no-store-actions.md)
- [persist middleware api](https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand/blob/main/docs/integrations/persisting-store-data.md#api)
- [middleware that changes store type](https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand/blob/main/docs/guides/typescript.md#middleware-that-changes-the-store-type)